# Popup in Firefox WebExtension only loading first javascript file

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm loading a popup via the `"browser_action"` option in `manifest.json`. The HTML file loads, and the FIRST script tag I declare loads, but the other two js files after it doesn't. The javascript is loaded at the bottom of the file, like so:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="const.js"/>
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="core.js"/>
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="options.js"/>
```

and the manifest looks like this:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "myExtension",
  "version": "1.1",

  "description": "myExtension",
  "icons": {
    "32": "chrome/skin/myExtension.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "chrome/icons/default/myExtension.ico",
    "default_title": "myExtension",
    "default_popup": "chrome/content/options.html"
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried with text/javascript?

Comment: @Smile4ever it doesn't seem to make any difference?

Comment: Have you tried placing them in another order, does it make a difference? Do they actually exist in chrome/content folder? On a side note, I don't understand why you have used the chrome/icons and chrome/content folders.